# Google Drive AP - list folders only with root folder in PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to list out the folders with root directory where user can select which folder they want to upload their files or the root directory.

Can I achieve this by putting the query in this line below ?

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to simply use [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) with `?q=` parameters to list out the folders with root directory.

It would look something like this: `q:mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed=false`

In the query above, it is filter on 3 criterias.

1. mimeType = application/vnd.google-apps.folder (Search for folders using the folder-specific MIME type)
2. 'root' in parents (Search for all files and folders located in the root)
3. trashed = false (Search for files which are not trashed)

You can try testing the query [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#tryit!).

In PHP code, that would be something like this:

```
$parameters['q'] = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed=false";
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is copied straight away from their [API documentation page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list).
You will need to specify a `$service` and a `$folderId`.

To get such an ID in GoogleDrive is a bit tricky and best done via their [search parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters). See my function `getSOFolderByName`() for an example (searchs for a folder called 'stackoverflow' and retrieves the first ID it can find). `listSOFolder()` is the starting point.

```
function listSOFolder($service) {
    $folderID = getSOFolderByName($service);
    if ($folderID)
        printFilesInFolder($service, $folderID);
}

function getSOFolderByName($service) {
    $search = "title='stackoverflow' AND mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed != true";
    $parameters = array("q" => $search);
    $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
    if (!empty($files["items"])) {
        $folderID = $files["items"][0]->getId(); // the first element
        return $folderID;
    } else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Print files belonging to a folder.
 * Copied shamelessly from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param String $folderId ID of the folder to print files from.
 */
function printFilesInFolder($service, $folderId) {
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $children = $service->children->listChildren($folderId, $parameters);

      foreach ($children->getItems() as $child) {
        print 'File Id: ' . $child->getId();
      }
      $pageToken = $children->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
}
```